# Parsing/Evaluating not to values, but saving the functions? So that parsing happens only once

Tags: f#

I'm trying to implement spreadsheet like functionality where it maintains variables and updates them correctly when other variables or "cells" change.

The only implementation I have seen so far is one that stores the inputted data in a string and evaluates it, however when data changes and cells need to be recalculated it always needs to evaluate the strings again.

What I'm simply wondering is if it's possible at all to parse a string like Cell1 = "SQUARED (4)"  into Cell1 = squared 4
So instead of the value being calculated into the cell, but the string needing to be run again and again when recalculations are necessary, it can instead save the actual functions and values somehow, somewhere, so that parsing and evaluating only needs to happen once.

If this isn't possible then I'll need to create a code-generator because I need things to be really fast and can't afford heavy performance loss. The speed of evaluation, compiling, ect, does not matter. It's the speed after all cells have been created, when the input data changes millions of times and propagates through the "spreadsheet" like system that matters.

So this is first of all just a yes or no question. If possible then any examples would of course be helpful. Edit: Well I guess it would be really helpful, since I can't figure this out myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a quite good example from Don Syme's blog on memoization - https://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx?Redirected=true

You write this function

```
let memoize f =
    let cache = Dictionary<_, _>()    
    fun x ->    
        if cache.ContainsKey(x) then cache.[x]    
        else let res = f x    
             cache.[x] <- res    
             res
```

Then you can create a memoized function like:

```
let memoizedAppend =
    memoize (fun input ->
        printfn "Working out the value for '%A'" input
        String.concat ", " [ for i in 0 .. 9 -> sprintf "%d: %s" i input ])
```

Comment: Wow that was extremely fast! If this is actually the answer, then wow thank you! It will probably take me some time to understand this better, so I'll report back soon :)

Comment: Just to make sure we're on the same note, I'm not calculating all the cells again and again, only when they need updating, they are notified, and for now re-evaluate the string, but I want it instead to just run its functions again. Will this help with that? - Because I've been reading on wikipedia and I'm not exactly sure this is what I need.

Comment: @user1594138 The idea is say you have:  `let evaluate cell = ....` you write `let m_evaluate = memoize evaluate` and then if you call `m_evaluate` with a repeated input, you get a value from cache without having to reevaluate your function.

Comment: yeah but things are only being updated, if they need to be updated, which means something has changed. So maybe I gave a bad example in my post, but most cells are based on other cells, and only update when notified that other cells changed that this cell relies upon. So Cell1 = cell2+cell3, Cell1 is only updated when cell2, or cell3 change. So while its the same string cell1 = "cell2+cell3", the data  has changed. I just simply want it to save the function instead of the string, so Cell1 = cell2+cell3, just like you would actually write it in pure code.

Comment: You could at least save part of the work - just have 2 stages - 1st stage goes from `string -> 't` where `'t` is some datatype which evaluates reasonably rapidly - and also could store dependencies but you then have to repeatedly evaluate the fast function.  I would suggest you just try the naive version first though - on modern hardware it may be fast enough.

Comment: Okay thanks for the help, I've chosen you as the best answer. Though I have decided to go with a code generator. It's easiest for me that way, for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 3):

If you're interested in implementing something like a spreadsheet, then there are two things that might help.

- Firstly, the [Cellz project](http://cellz.codeplex.com/) is a sample implementation of a spreadsheet in F#. It includes a simple parser for strings like "=SUM(A1:A10)" and builds an expression tree from these strings (and this is done just once). Secondly, it also includes an evaluator that calculates the value of an expression.
- Secondly, Luca Bolognese had a few talks about the implementation of calculation framework called "Eden" where you describe computations in terms of cells and when a value in a cell changes, the change gets propagated automatically (and only dependent cells are recalculated). He will be speaking at [TechMesh London 2012](http://techmeshconf.com/techmesh-london-2012/presentation/Eden%3a%20An%20F#/WPF%20framework%20for%20building%20GUI%20tools), but I think this has been recorded somewhere (but cannot find it).

The basic idea behind Eden is that a cell is represented as something that has a current value and an event that is triggered when the value changes:

```
type Cell<'T> =
  abstract Value : 'T  
  abstract Changed : IEvent<unit>
```

A cell that is created and mutated explicitly has mutable `Value` and triggers the event when the value is changed by the user:

```
type MutableCell<'T>(value:'T) = 
  let mutable currentValue = value
  let event = Event<unit>()
  member x.Value 
    with get() = currentValue
    and set(v) = 
        currentValue <- v
        event.Trigger()
  interface Cell<'T> with 
    member x.Value = currentValue
    member x.Changed = event.Publish
```

Then you can also construct cells that are produced as a result of some calculation. This is a topic for a talk or a blog post and not an SO answer, but a simple transformation that maps a value in a cell to another cell would look like this:

```
let map f (cell:Cell<_>) =
  let currentValue = ref (f cell.Value)
  cell.Changed.Add(fun () -> currentValue := f cell.Value) 
  { new Cell<_> with
      member x.Value = currentValue.Value
      member x.Changed = cell.Changed }
```

You need to be able to combine values from multiple cells etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think I didn't write my question well enough because I know all this. I've looked at the cellz source code and understand it pretty well, it's exactly that kind of style I'm asking if its possible to not do. The problem with it is exactly what I typed, it calls the entire evaluation / parsing functions, and all that overhead crap for each and EVERY time a cell needs to be recalculated. All I'm asking if that can be skipped, and that the parser simply sets the values to how you would write it in actual code. So cell1 = cell2+1 , instead of cell1 = evaluate "cell2+1"

Comment: So it simply somehow, evaluates cell1 to equal cell1 = cell2+1. It looks like its not possible and I'll simply have to create a code generator. So I will simply type in Cell1 = cell2+1, and it will create the object, the cell entry, dependancies, ect, all in normal code, without any of the evaluation except just to generate the code in the code generator.

Comment: Sorry though this might have been a very stupid question, I just don't know what is possible and what isn't. I think I'll simply create a code generator to have things as efficient as they can be, thanks for the help!

Comment: Okay I've pretty much made myself confused because I have no clue what I'm talking about. But I guess to sum it up, I'm just seeing if its possible to skip dealing with strings. I believe the evaluator needs to evaluate a string, match it vs endless functions, ect, while I want there to be no strings, and its just directly connected to the correct function, ect. Anyway I'm going the code generator way.

Comment: FSharp 3.0 sample pack has example of portable spreadsheet (http://fsharp3sample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/17472#254239) that doesn't reparse dependent cells during evaluation. Parsing happens only once after user typed formula and it results into AST. Now formula evalutation just interprets AST but in general nothing prevents you from going further.

Comment: @desco Thank you! Always good to have more spreadsheet examples. Can you maybe give an example when you say nothing prevents one from going further? Do you mean its possible to interpret the AST just once? And if so do you know how?

Comment: I mean that now result of parsing is AST. By further I mean that you can i.e build a dynamic method based on AST so evaluation will use compiled code instead of AST interpretation

Comment: @desco Cool, that's sounds like what I was looking to do! Should I just search for dynamic methods, to learn more or?

Comment: @desco or I mean is there something more particular I could search for?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.dynamicmethod.aspx

Comment: The Cellz parser, parses the cell string to an AST when you edit the cell, it does not parse the string on evaluation. If you need to go faster you could transform the AST to code using CodeDOM or Reflection.Emit. I wrote a cut down version of Cellz as a tutorial a while back which you may find useful: http://www.developerfusion.com/article/123830/functional-cells-a-spreadsheet-in-f/